# How to set up Virtualbox 1366x768 resolution for a Linux guest?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, vmware, linux-mint

I have been trying maybe weeks now to figure out how to configure `VirtualBox` to have 1366x768 resolution on a `linux` guest, which is on a windows 8.1 host.

My configuration:

- Windows 8.1 as host
- Linuxmint 17.1 as guest (tried ubuntu and debian too but no luck)
- Virtualbox 4.3.26 and its extension pack
- Laptop is powerful with 16GB ram and 4GB Nvdia

My problem is that it doesn't matter what I used, *nothing* worked.

Please do not post the answers on most known websites, I tried them already.

Comment: What's the maximum resolution does show the `xrandr -q`?

Comment: "Please do not post the answers on most known websites, I tried them already". That pretty much covers everything. So perhaps you can say exactly what you have tried otherwise you may not get many answers.

Comment: I tried    VBoxManage.exe setextradata "myLinux" CustomVideoMode1 1366x768x32

Comment: Come on now! Nobody is using at 1366x768 on Virtualbox?

Answer (score 2):

Once your VM is started, you need to run the VBox Linux Guest Additions.

1. First try to run it from the VirtualBox window's menu:

> Devices >> Insert guest Additions CD image...

and follow the instructions.

2. If that fails, open a terminal and go to the directory where you CD reader is mounted (/run/media/ on Fedora or /media/ on Ubuntu for example).
   Then type command `sudo ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run`

Complete instructions can be found on the [VirtualBox user manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html)

Once Guest Additions are installed, reboot your virtual machine. You should be able to resize your screen to your heart's content.

Answer (score 0):

I installed the new VirtualBox 5.0.0_BETA2 and it solved my all problems. Great product is getting ready! Cant wait the latest release. more than a PERFECT software. Now you can remove top bar and/or bottom bar easily. Show what you need.
If you are having problem like me with 1366x768 I recommend you to install latest versin of VB even if it is Beta!